# C# Constructor Referencing

Tags: c#

Given code like

```
public class classname
{
    public classname()
    {
        type variablename = new type();
    }
    public typeb variablename {get; private set;}
}
```

there are two variables called `variablename` of different types.

When I create a new object type classname, does the property object.variablename return an object of type, or typeb?

How does the referencing work in conjunction with the constructor?  If I want to retrieve typeb variablename vs type variablename, how do I do so?

Update:
Small code edit above, changing the variable access to public.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and upvote this.  It seems like a reasonable question for a beginner to ask.  Also editing the question for clarity.

Comment: For future reference, what keywords might I search to find an answer to questions like this?

Comment: Your core issue is variable scope.  Searching `variable scope c#` turns up some good results on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I create a new object type classname, does the property object.variablename return an object of type, or typeb?

You must first make `typeb variablename` accessible outside of the class.  After that, accessing object.variablename would access the property of type `typeb`.

> How does the referencing work in conjunction with the constructor? If I want to retrieve typeb variablename vs type variablename, how do I do so?

The code

```
type variablename = new type(); // Semicolon was missing
```

is only defined within the scope of your constructor.  It is completely inaccessible outside of it.

The code

```
typeb variablename {get; private set;}
```

is a private property of the class.  Anywhere within the class, other than in the constructor, `variablename` will refer to this property.

Note that you do not initialize this property, so it will have its default value (which is null for object types).

If you want to expose `variablename` outside of the class, or to derived classes, you will need to use an access modifier to express that, e.g.

```
public typeb variablename {get; private set;}
```

If you change your constructor to

```
public classname()
{
    variablename = new type();
}
```

it will initialize your property, if `type` can be assigned to `typeb`.  See [covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).